# Подключаться к VK API через свой аккаунт

Tags: oauth, php, вконтакте

Нужно: чтобы приложение по введеному запросу искало видео клипы.
Для этого нужен доступ `access_token` и чтобы получить его, нужна авторизация в ВК, но я не хочу, чтобы пользователи каждый раз автиризировались сами, вдруг у них нет ВК. У меня есть свой аккаунт, можно ли каким-нибудь образом постоянно авторизироваться через готовый логин и пароль?

- язык - php
- принимаю респонсы в JSON

Comment: Вы хотите авторизоваться на стороне клиента? Не боитесь, что клиент сменит ваш пароль?

Comment: теперь боюсь, но что Вы предлагаете делать?

Comment: Я бы сказал, требовать, чтобы клиент сам авторизовался. (Перекидывать на страницу авторизации, если не авторизован.) Нету экаунта в VK — так пусть заведёт, делов-то!

Альтернатива — пусть с VK общается сервер, на котором бежит ваша авторизация. Учтите, что если клиенты будут искать что-то запрещённое законом, вопросы будут к владельцу экаунта, то есть к вам.

Comment: Ой, извините, случайно удалил ваш комментарий вместо своего.

---
На стороне клиента — не знаю, как. На стороне сервера проще. :-)

Comment: !!! идеально, пусть будет на стороне сервера, так даже лучше, но как это делается? я плохо понимаю документацию вк, если там есть нужный топик и я его прозевал, дайте ссылку и простите за невнимательность

Comment: Хм, стыдно признаться, но я её не читал. Я вообще не web-разработчик.

Comment: посмотрел, серверная авторизация есть, там вообще ничего не нужно толком, но и самые нужные функции тоже закрыты, отпадает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно авторизироваться самому, на сервере. При этом Вы скорее всего захотите использовать `offline` в `scope` (см. Документацию).
Однако далеко с этим Вы все равно не уйдёте. Если сайт будет популярным, может возникнуть проблема с количеством запросов в секунду.